# Chrome extension like Tamper Data

Tags: chrome, http

Tamper Data is a Firefox add-on to track and modify HTTP/HTTPS requests.

Is there a Google Chrome extension that can do the same?

Comment: Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869711/is-there-an-extension-like-tamperdata-for-chrome)

Comment: @RahilWazir those answers are outdated. It can be done now. I just don't know an extension which can do it as smoothly as Firefox's Tamper Data

Comment: @Ranveer can you point me to Chrome API (or blog post or something like that) that tells tampering outgoing requests is possible now? I'm pretty sure it's not. Remember that it's really different to modify outgoing request or to generate a new request.

Comment: And instead of non-existing extension, you can use proxy, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5020686/592174) recommends [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Burb](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) to achieve same thing with any browser.

Answer (score 2):

Rahil Wazir's comment is correct. But, [the right answer has sunk to the bottom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-maker/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp) and was not well reasoned (perhaps back then it couldn't do this?)

> You can easily capture requests made by web pages, tamper with the URL, headers, and `POST` data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RestEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/). Just put in all the headers, save the capture and then once you do that, you can modify the body to whatever data fits. I suggest using Inspect Element to retrieve the POST data. It is a one-way workaround, because technically, you can't edit http requests, but I found that you can fire your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DevTools (Console Chrome Developer Tools) which are designed for that.

However it's probably not possible to modify HTTP requests in Chrome due to API restrictions<sup>[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854671/55075)</sup>.

Some workarounds include:

- [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)
- [Change HTTP Request Header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-http-request-heade/ppmibgfeefcglejjlpeihfdimbkfbbnm?hl=en)
- [Request Maker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-maker/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp)
- [Postman app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

or using proxies:

- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- [Fiddler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddler/hkknfnifmbannmgkdliadghepbneplka)

From API perspective, check [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tamper Dev (http://tamper.dev).

You press Alt + T and that starts intercepting all requests from the currently open Tab.